# Batch-file seems to be cached

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script which calls another like this;

```
call \\myserver\mypath\myfile.bat
```

This has been working ok for around 6 years. However i recently made a change to the batch script that gets called by this line. I quickly realised my change was causing a problem so i reverted my changes.

However it seems that some clients are still calling my modified script. As if they have a cached copy. Is this possible? If so how can i clear the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using offline files. So the batch file i was editing was a local copy on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

yes, batch files are cached if you try to execute them from a remote computer over the network.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365201(v=vs.85).aspx

> One type of application that can benefit from local caching is batch files. Command processors read and execute a batch file one line at a time. For each line, the command processor opens the file, searches to the beginning of the line, reads as much as it needs, closes the file, then executes the line. Each line results in a lot of network traffic. Network traffic can be reduced considerably by caching the entire batch file on a client.

i believe you can disable caching using `net share` command's `/cache:no` parameter.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490712.aspx

Of course you can do the same thing using "Properties->Sharing->Advanced Sharing->Caching" section from Windows interface.

Comment: I tried this, but users are still getting cached copy of the batch file.

Comment: Well, actually "Transparent Caching" is disabled by default and not used until there is a slow network. But maybe it is enabled for some reason. Please check it using this link (http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/networking/q-how-do-i-enable-transparent-caching-in-windows-7-) and disable if it is enabled. i'm not sure if that's the case but this may overwrite some options.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using [Console2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/)) it helped to open a new terminal tab. It seems the caching was done by the terminal, not the operating system.